# basic phone number validating regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What would be the regex code to validate a number, the number should only be read if it is in between 10-13 digits

I'm using this Regex: /\d([0-9]{11,13})\z/

The problem is it should only accept digits between 11 and 13 if it exceeds 13 it still accepts it.

I want it to simply validate these kind of numbers:

`12345678910   = 11 Digits 
 123456789101  = 12 Digits`

Comment: You need to anchor the match from the beginning to the end./ Something such as `/^\d([0-9]{11,13})$\z/` (notice the `^` and `$`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Regex matches the following:

- `\d`, that is a number character
- followed by 11, 12 or 13 characters from the range of 0-9
- followed by the end of the string

As such, your regular expression currently matches a numeric string with between 12 and 14 numeric chars at the end. It does not match a numeric string containing only 11 characters. Anything at the start of the string before that is ignored (i.e. your regex would also match `foobar 1234567891012`)

To fix your regex, you could simplify it to

```
/\A\d{10,13}\z/
```

This regex would match the following:

- the start of the string
- followed by 10 to 13 numeric characters
- followed by the end of the string